# How to resize column in row for responsive screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I am build app landing page in Flutter for web. I need make page responsive for different screen size.

I am use `MediaQuery` for change layout for small screen so widget are layout vertical.

But for medium size screen layout is horizontal. So I need resize app screenshot when screen is make smaller. How to do?

For example: [reflectly.app](https://reflectly.app)

Here my code so far:

```
Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  CenterText(),
                                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                                  Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      DownloadButtons()                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Screenshot(),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the `LayoutBuilder` component, which is what you want and fixes your needs.

`LayoutBuilder` takes two parameters, one is a `context`, the second is a `constraints`. With those constraints you can set show different layouts for different screens.

Check this example:

```
LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          if(constraints.maxHeight < 768 && constraints.maxWidth < 1270) {
            return smallDesignContent();
          } else {
            return bigDefaultDesignContent();
          }
        },
      )
```

[Flutter Widget of the Week - Layout Builder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYDVcriKjsw)

[Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply! I know `LayoutBuilder` but my issue is I need make screenshot proportionate smaller based on screen size, not just one size or another size. Look at reflectly.app

Comment: No problem, you can set more than one condition, it's up to you, if you want to check if height and width is less than 300 both, you can. Have fun ahaha

Comment: I've pointed only one example, you can have as many as you should